# How can I retrieve array of data from api stored in a localStorage in ionic

Tags: arrays, api, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have been trying to pass data returned from a php api across all pages of my app but to no avail. I have made series search on google as well on this platform but all aborted.

I have this lines of code which uses a user username after login to fetch the user's details from mysql through the api.

Now, when the user information is fetch, which is an array, I want to store that array into ionic local storage and retrieve it from anywhere in my app.

Below is my code:

**user.ts**

```
 ngOnInit(){

this.username = this.navParams.get('username');


var headers = new Headers();

headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

let data = {

    username: this.username

     };

let loader = this.loading.create({

content: 'Preparing your page',

});

loader.present().then(() => {

this.http.post('http://edmon.com/api/retrieve.php',data, options)

.map(res => res.json())

    .subscribe(res => {

     loader.dismiss()

    this.items=res.server_response;

    console.log(this.items);

    });

    });
    //this.navCtrl.push(PostPage, data); 


     }

//Store to storage
     saveData() {
      var jsonObj = this.items;
      window.localStorage.setItem('myJsonKey', JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
      //console.log('my itmes:', jsonObj);
     }
```

How can I go about it as to be able to get those data from anywhere in the app?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share the logs and errors for clarifying your issue.

Comment: @HyuckKang, I am not having issues, I am only asking how I can store returned array from => this.http.post('http://edmon.com/api/retrieve.php',data, options) .map(res => res.json())

    .subscribe(res => {

     loader.dismiss()

    this.items=res.server_response;

    console.log(this.items);

    });

    }); to a storage and retrive it anywhere in my app.

Answer (score 0):

make **saveData()** like the below

```
saveData(item:any) {
  window.localStorage.setItem('myJsonKey', JSON.stringify(item));
}
```

And then, use it like the below

```
loader.present().then(() => {

 this.http.post('http://edmon.com/api/retrieve.php',data, options)

 .map(res => res.json())

 .subscribe(res => {

   loader.dismiss()

   //this.items=res.server_response;
   //console.log(this.items);
   this.saveData(res.server_response)
  });

});
```

**--update--**

make **getData()** function in other page. Or it is better to make **Service** to save and load item via storage. please refer [angular service tutorrials](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).

```
getData():Promise<any>{
  return new Promise<any>((resolve,reject)=>{
    window.localStorage.getItem('myJsonKey').then((item)=>{
      resolve(JSON.parse(item))
    }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err); reject()})
  }); 
}
```

if you are familiar with `async` and  `await`, consider the below simple version.

```
async getData():Promise<any>{
  try{
    let item = await window.localStorage.getItem('myJsonKey')
    return JSON.parse(item)
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
    throw ''
  }
}
```

**Usage**

`this.getData().then(...)`

Comment: thanks for the reply. But please, how should I display it in another page? Let say if I want to show the details on profile.html for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Here is when you store the data to `localStorage`.

```
 //Store to storage
 saveData() {
     var jsonObj = this.items;
     window.localStorage.setItem('myJsonKey', JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
     //console.log('my itmes:', jsonObj);
 }
```

And here is when you want to get the data anywhere in your app.

```
//Get from storage
getData(){
    window.localStorage.getItem('myJsonKey').then( data => {

        // if you want to convert it back to JSON
        // create variable retData in your ts file
        // retData = any;

        this.retData = JSON.parse(data);

    });
}
```

Cleaner way is to make your own provider and place all methods for storage management there. Then call these methods in your ts.

For example, you set your methods in `user-service.ts` under provider folder. Create your methods like `setData()` or `getData()`, and how they will work.

And then in your ts file, import your `user-service.ts` provider and call the methods.